# using elasticsearch.js is no result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch

I want show elastic search data on web page that using angular js.
however,  not bring data from elasticsearch with that message
Is there anything I need to add or fix in my code?
if anyone answers to me I really appreciate

I have attached an execution screen.

thank you.

Execution screen: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9ILA.png)

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="QueryController"></div>

<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/elasticsearch-browser/elasticsearch.angular.js"></script>
<script>


    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['elasticsearch']);


    // Create the es service from the esFactory


    myApp.service('es', function (esFactory) {
        return esFactory({ host: 'http://localhost:9200'});
    });

    myApp.controller('ServerHealthController', function($scope, es, esFactory) {

        es.cluster.health(function (err, resp) {
            if (err) {
                $scope.data = err.message;

            } else {
                $scope.data = resp;

            }
        });
    });

    // We define an Angular controller that returns query results,
    // Inputs: $scope and the 'es' service

    myApp.controller('QueryController', function($scope, es, esFactory) {


// search for documents
        es.search({
            index: 'epowersyst',
            type: 'logs',
            body: {
              query:
                {
                  "match_all" : {} }
                }

        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.hits = response;
            console.log($scope.hits)


        }).catch(function (err) {
          if (err.status === 404) {
            alert("error 404" );

          } else {
            alert("error : " + err );

          }
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code from the front. (angularjs) looks good, the problem is the backend, check your logs to see what is missing.

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't know how check the log
can you tell me how?
plaease~~~ i relly thank you

Comment: try to check the CORS allowed. the screenshot you share are broken in the OPTIONS method thats a cors issue, check in the configuration of your api, to allow options method.

Comment: I added this part to elasticsearch.yml.                                         

http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin:"*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length
http.cors.allow-credentials:true           

but.. it did not work out.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco please..I will ask you for help.

Comment: sorry dude without the log, cant help to much, to tell what to do.